# Different polygons same angles no parallel sides

Tags: geometry

Does anyone know a formal proof, or reference that supports the next fact:

Two closed polygons, with the same number of sides, and congruent  angles, are one each other and scaled version if they do not have any parallel edge.

Comment: "... are one each other and scaled version..." What does that mean?

Comment: Take any trapezoid, slant the base slightly so that no two sides are parallel any longer, then translate the base downwards without rotation. All angles stay the same, but the quadrilateral continuosly changes.

Comment: I believe it might mean something like this: "Suppose $P$ is a polygon with no pairwise parallel sides (e.g., trapezoids are not allowed). Suppose $Q$ is another such polygon, and has the same sequence of angles as those of $P$. Then there's a rigid motion $R$ and a homothety $H$ such that $H(R(P)) = Q$."

Comment: (I also agree with @dxiv that the conjecture is almost certainly false.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're suggesting that two polygons (lacking parallel edges) with matching angle sequences are similar, then here's a counterexample:

[image]

Comment: NICE! You basically chopped the head off a triangle at two different heights. Can't believe I initially thought this was true. I must go to the maths doctor and get my intuition checked out.

Comment: @ColmBhandal: The "chopped triangle" interpretation is somewhat specific to this counterexample (which I concocted to provide "obviously" incompatible segment-wise scale factors, $2:1$, $1:2$, $1:1$, and "none of the above"). However, there's no reason a counter-example has to involve a chopped triangle. In general, segments $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BC}$ can be *however long we like*, and there'll be some $\overline{CD}$ and $\overline{DA}$ to close the figure, with the angle at $D$ determined by the angles at $A$, $B$, $C$.